# Handling Multiple Classes in Categorical independent variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

The dataset has 4 categorical and 1 numerical variable and a timestamp variable. Out of 4, three categorical variables are having more than 100 categories. I do not have a labelled variable for this data. Size of the dataset is 1 million rows.

I tried doing one-hot encoding on the whole dataset using "pd.get_dummies()" method and the number of columns increased from 6 to 6000. And the time consumption to do the dummy variables took more than 3 minutes.

When you want to use these variables to build a model using machine learning to detect anomalies, how should the categorical variables be handled if you have a dataset of a million rows? Should this be considered as a time-series data but you can data for every day but not recorded in fixed intervals? What models can be applied to this kind of dataset?